# Read value of input field and automatically assign var type using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have dozens of input fields and need to parse each of them into a object with key/value pairs. I can do that easily using this here

```
var myobj = {};
$(this).find('.stuff').each(function (e) {
  var key = $(this).attr('name');
  var val = $(this).val();
  myobj[key] = val;
}).promise().done(function (e) {
   // do more stuff
});
```

However, each value is parsed as string but some of them are int and some of them are decimals. How can I parse them automatically? Do I need to add e.g. a class to each input and parse them using e.g. `switch`?

Comment: You can use `<input type="number">` (along with the `step` attribute for decimals) to both control what data can be entered and let you identify if the value should be parsed as a number or not.

Comment: Side note, why are you making a promise off of a synchronous operation of each() ?

Comment: possible duplicate, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834901/jquery-automatic-type-conversion-during-parse-json

Comment: @ShubhamSingla I believe not, here I don't know per se, what type I'm currently reading

Comment: There are a bunch of 'is*' methods you can potentially use to check to see if the string matches various things before you parse in whatever manner you choose.  http://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/   Typically markup attribute values are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
if(!isNaN(val)) {
    val = Number(val);
}
```

Try placing that under the line

```
var val = $(this).val();
```

Comment: @RobertStettler See my edit. I think that should work :)

Comment: Why the `, 10`?

Comment: @RobertStettler Just thought, you should also need to check if val is an empty string. I don't know if that is ever something that could happen but you should still check for it.

Comment: @MaxO'Brien `Number()` doesn't take a second parameter, `parseInt()` does. `Number()` uses the format of the string to infer base.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Ahh very true. Sorry that was a carry over from the first version I had with parseInt(). I have edited the answer now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.type()` to test for the difference then act accordingly.

```
var x = 123;
var y = $.type(x);
alert(y); //alerts "number"
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/).