# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Tags: android, retrofit, illegalstateexception, retrofit2

I have written a `Login` functionality and to **communicate** with `web service` I am using **Retrofit** but always getting **"Failed"**

**Getting:**

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

**LoginAPI.java:**

```
public interface LoginApi {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/retrofit_user/login.php")
    public void getlogin(
        @Field("username") String username,
        @Field("password") String password,
        Callback<User> response);
}
```

**LoginActivity.java:**

```
restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(ROOT_LOGIN).build();
restAdapter.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
loginApi = restAdapter.create(LoginApi.class);

buttonlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

  loginApi.getlogin(editTextUsername.getText().toString(),
  editTextPassword.getText().toString(), new Callback<User>() {

  @Override
  public void success(User s, Response response) {
     Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Logged In",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(s != null) {
       Log.d("name:", s.getName());
       Log.d("email:", s.getEmail());
       Log.d("id:", String.valueOf(s.getId()));
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

       Log.d("error:", error.toString());
 Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      });
    }
});
```

**User.java:**

```
public class User {

    String name;
    String username;
    String password;
    String email;
    int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**Log says**

```
D/Retrofit: <--- HTTP 200 http://domain.info/retrofit_user/login.php (942ms)
D/Retrofit: : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
D/Retrofit: Connection: Keep-Alive
D/Retrofit: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
D/Retrofit: Date: Sat, 20 Feb 2016 06:00:39 GMT
D/Retrofit: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
D/Retrofit: Server: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
D/Retrofit: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
D/Retrofit: X-Android-Received-Millis: 1455948038590
D/Retrofit: X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 200
D/Retrofit: X-Android-Selected-Transport: http/1.1
D/Retrofit: X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1455948037988
D/Retrofit: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.14
D/Retrofit: Done
D/Retrofit: <--- END HTTP (4-byte body)
D/error:: retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
D/GraphicBuffer: create handle(0x55bb2e98) (w:256, h:66, f:1)
D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x55bb2e98) (w:256 h:66 f:1)
```

And here is my `login.php` script:

```
<?php

    $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
    $objDB = mysql_select_db("database");

    /*** for sample */
    // $_POST["username"] = "sun";
    // $_POST["password"] = "live";

    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

    $strSQL = "select * from test_users where username = '".$username."' and  password = '".$password."' ";

    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    $intNumRows = mysql_num_rows($objQuery);

    if($intNumRows==0)
    {
    echo "Not Done" ;
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Done" ;
    }

    mysql_close($objConnect);
?>
```

Comment: your request is returning HTTP/1.1 200 OK. 200 code is for successful request. I don't think there is any issue with retrofit

Comment: Yeah but my question is why I am getting Login failed

Comment: Log the `error` variable in `failure` method. What does it say?

Comment: @KNeerajLal Just checked getting: D/error:: retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: I think your inteface method is not correct. If I were you I would have been written it like this Callback<User> getlogin(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password).

Comment: @Sun add `User` class code.

Comment: @KNeerajLal posted...

Comment: @Sun See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, retrofit expects a `JSON` output that it can fit into `User` class from `login.php`, but all the `login.php` gives is "Not Done" or "Done".

You have to make your php script output json in the following format,

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "email": "email",
    "id": id
}
```

You have to edit the php code. It will be something like this,

```
<?php
    $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
    $objDB = mysql_select_db("database");

    /*** for sample */
    // $_POST["username"] = "sun";
    // $_POST["password"] = "live";

    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

    $strSQL = "select * from test_users where username = '".$username."' and  password = '".$password."' ";

    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    $intNumRows = mysql_num_rows($objQuery);
    if($intNumRows==0)
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["name"] = "";
        $response["username"] = "";
        $response["password"] = "";
        $response["email"] = "";
        $response["id"] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["name"] = $row["name"];
        $response["username"] = $row["username"];
        $response["password"] = $row["password"];
        $response["email"] = $row["email"];
        $response["id"] = $row["id"];
    }

    mysql_close($objConnect);

    echo json_encode($response, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

Also add a `int success;` field to `User` class and use it to validate the output. So your success method will be,

```
@Override
public void success(User s, Response response) {
    if(s != null && s.getSuccess() == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Logged In",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("name:", s.getName());
        Log.d("email:", s.getEmail());
        Log.d("id:", String.valueOf(s.getId()));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Invalid!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

**Update**

The `id` field is a `int` in database stil it returns id as a string. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390983/php-json-encode-encoding-numbers-as-strings) thread. Adding `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` to `json_encode()` in php will help.

Comment: I tried and it works, but getting id in " " double quotes, here is the output of my php: {"success":1,"name":"Sun Live","username":"sun","password":"live","email":"sun@live.ifno","id":"1"}

Comment: no bro id field in an integer field: id     Primary   int(11)