# CakePHP 2.x JSON views are encoding numbers as strings

Tags: php, json, cakephp

Is there a way to get CakePHP 2.8 JSON views to encode numbers as numbers instead of strings?

I would like to avoid creating `/json/*.ctp` view files with `echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)` if at all possible and have the standard `_serialize` method below encode numbers properly by default.

```
public function index(){
    $items = $this->Paginator->paginate();

     $this->set(array(
        'items' => $items,
        '_serialize' => array('items')
    ));
}
```

Comment: Are the item fields actual numbers to begin with? Sometime when they come from the database you might actually get strings instead.

Comment: You might want to take a look at a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6608413/4073621.

Comment: Yes, the fields are numbers in the DB. I know about `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` but I was wondering if there was a way to turn that on without using it in a view file.

Comment: can you please specify the output of $member_forms as JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK will convert `<?php
// International phone number
json_encode(array('phone_number' => '+33123456789'), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>` to {"phone_number":33123456789}

Comment: The numbers in this case are of type `int`.