# How to remove double quotes of json_encode array

Tags: php, json

I want to be able to remove double quotes that in my json_encode:

```
 $response = array(
        "response" => true,
        "ack_move" => array(
            "slot" => $move,
            "isWin" => false,
            "isDraw" => false,
            "row" => array()
        );
echo json_encode($response);
```

My result is:

```
{"response":true,"ack_move":{"slot":"3","isWin":false,"isDraw":false,"row":[]}
```

I want to remove the double quotes of the integer "3"

How can I do a result is that:

```
{"response":true,"ack_move":{"slot":3,"isWin":false,"isDraw":false,"row":[]}
```

Comment: Did you try `"slot" => (int)$move,`

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6608413/283366) from the duplicate post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using function intval($move) to get the integer value, and then assign the value.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php