# How do I make column alias to be in integer?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I had this line of query

```
$sql = " SELECT c.name, IF(a.addressid IS NOT NULL,0,1) AS checked
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN addresses a 
ON c.customerid = a.customerid
WHERE customerid = 123 ";

$array     = array();
$GetResult = $Obj->FetchData($sql, $Obj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);
while ($row = $GetResult->fetch()) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
header("Content-type: application/json");
$result = json_encode($array);
echo $result;
```

when I echo in JSON format it show my `checked` output as a string. And I wonder by default what data type for alias `checked`? And how can I change into integer data type?

Comment: @HoneyBadger Here I edit the post.

Comment: A column alias will acquire the data type from the underlying data , I cannot remember if this is by scanning data or from the table definition- if in doubt force it by using cast or convert.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer, yes by default it already in data type number, the problem in `json` format. It produce my `checked` as string. So I found the answer here [PHP json_encode encoding numbers as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390983/php-json-encode-encoding-numbers-as-strings).

> $result = json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

Answer (score 0):

i have added a convert function of that column to represent an integer type. hopefully that will translate to your desired result

```
SELECT c.name, Convert(IF(a.addressid IS NOT NULL,0,1), unsigned integer) AS checked
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN addresses a 
ON c.customerid = a.customerid
WHERE customerid = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cast` or `convert`, full [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html).

So it would be similar to:

```
SELECT c.name, cast(if(a.addressid is not null, 0, 1) as unsigned) as checked
```