# How to get values from database and put it in a certain bracket in a php file that is json_encoded?

Tags: php, json, mapbox, geojson

Here's my code:

```
<?php 

session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'id128XXXXX', 'LXXXX');

mysqli_select_db($con, 'idXXXXXX');

$query = "select * from sensor order by id desc limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


$value = array( 
    "geometry"=>array( 
        "type"=> "Point", 
        "coordinates"=> [0,0] ///I want to get values from a database and put it in this bracket.
    ) , 

    "type"=>"Feature", 
    "properties" => (object) array()
); 

// Use json_encode() function 
$json = json_encode($value); 

// Display the output 
echo($json); 

?>
```

Any help regarding this will be much appreciated thank you. As for what I've tried. I tried using

```
 "coordinates"=> [$row[longitude],$row[lat]]
```

ended up giving me this type of output:

```
{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":["0","0"]},"type":"Feature","properties":{}}
```

i need the ["0","0"] to be [0,0] since with the added quotation marks the map marker will not show up. And if anyone is asking I'm using mapbox and i need to output this json data for the map marker to keep refreshing.

Comment: More specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/6608413/1213708 which would be something like `$json = json_encode( $value, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK )`

Answer (score 0):

Convert the results to integers:

```
"coordinates"=> [intval($row['longitude']), intval($row['lat'])]
```

And don't forget to quote strings `longitude` and `lat`.