# Selecting number from SQL Server adds .0

Tags: json, sql-server, sqlsrv

When I select a column in SQL Server and then print it, 3 becomes 3.0.

This is my connection:

```
$sql = new PDO("sqlsrv:Driver=$driver;server=$server,$port;Database=$database;ConnectionPooling=0", $uid, $pwd,
        array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        )
    );
```

This is my `SELECT`:

```
$sth = $sql->prepare("SELECT column FROM table
                      WHERE column2 = :value2");
    
$params = array(':value2' => $_POST['value2']);
    
$sth->execute($params);
$result = $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   
echo json_encode($result);
```

- In SQL Server database: 3
- In echo: 3.0

What can be the reason for adding `.0`?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6608413/673707

Comment: @Zhorov I'm having problems with intergrating "This" into my select. I have no second value like: $sth->bindColumn('Antal', ?, PDO::PARAM_INT); And the second "...NUMERIC_TYPE" did no change.

Comment: @Zhorov PHP 8.0 driver 5.10

Comment: @Zhorov In MSSQL it's float

Comment: @BjörnC, did you try `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_FETCHES_NUMERIC_TYPE , true);` to check the difference?

Comment: @BjörnC, a hint: `$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); $stmt->execute(); $result = array(); $stmt->bindColumn('column', $column, PDO::PARAM_INT); while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND) ){$result[]["column"] = $column;}; echo json_encode($result);`.