# Symfony/Doctrine: Why my integer Entity attribute is returning as string?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an Entity with an attribute defined as following:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="weight", type="integer")
 */
private $weight;
```

I was trying to solve a bug and used var_dump() to have some clue of what was happening...

The response was:

```
string '20' (length=2)
```

I don't understand why $weight is returning as string... shouldn't it be an integer?

```
int 20
```

Or should I handle it in my business logic?

---

**Edit (how I called var_dump()):**

I have a class named "Calculator" that iterates $items and use the $weight attribute. Is something like this:

**Controller:**

```
$calculator->calculate($category->getItems());
```

**Calculator:**

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    //logic...

    var_dump($item->getWeight());
}
```

---

**Edit (database column schema):**

Here is the field in database:

```
weight  int(11)
```

Comment: what did you var_dump? show code

Comment: Hi, I added some details... thanks

Comment: how are the values stored in your database ? does the colum scheme match ?

Comment: Yes, it is defined as "int(11)"

Answer (score 0):

What **version of PHP** and **MySQL driver** are you using ?

I don't know exactly how Symfony casts (or not) the database results, but if you're using PHP 5.2, it can be quite normal : any variable you get from MySQL in PHP is always a string, even if it's an integer in the database.

In PHP 5.3, it's different, if you use the correct driver (`mysqlnd` — See http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2008/pdo_mysqlnd-the-new-features-of-pdo_mysql/)

See this answer for more details :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430657/1741150

Hope that helps !

Comment: Hi, I'm using "PHP 5.4.40" and "PDO" (through Doctrine ORM/Symfony)

Comment: Is your `getItems()` casting any objects in any way ?

Comment: It is just returning the Collection:

    /**
     * Get items
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->items;
    }