# First result of Stored Procedure is missing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I execute query of stored procudure which have 3 result of select

```
select _id a;
select 2 a;
select 3 a;
```

and I've mysqli like this to call the Stored Procedure

```
$i = 0;
if ($server->connection->query("CALL sp_select(1)", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
    printf("res\n");
    do {
        $i++;
        printf("$i.do\n");
        if ($result = $server->connection->store_result()) {
            printf("$i.store\n");
            $data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $this->data[] = $data;
            $result->free_result();
            printf("$i.free\n");
        }
        if ($server->connection->more_results()) {
            printf("$i.more\n");
        }
    } while ($server->connection->next_result());
    echo json_encode($this->data);
}
```

That function can't get stored first result. I only got second and third result.
Why I can't get stored first result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling stored procedure with `mysqli_query()` the first result is returned from the function itself. Something like this should also gather the first result.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("CALL sp_select()");
$this->data[] = $result->fetch_all();
while ($mysqli->next_result()) {
    if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        $this->data[] = $result->fetch_all();
    }
}
echo json_encode($this->data);
```

It looks like you mixed up `query()` with `multi_query()` which does not return the initial result. This code will do the same:

```
$mysqli->multi_query("CALL sp_select()");
do {
    if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        $this->data[] = $result->fetch_all();
    }
} while ($mysqli->next_result());
echo json_encode($this->data);
```

Comment: yeah. thanks this code work for me. but why all field is string. how to make field actual type?

Comment: @Youngzie See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31799686/1839439