# How to convert Codeigniter DB return string object to int

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    $sql = "SELECT catgy.category_id, catgy.category_title 
            FROM categories catgy
              INNER JOIN subj_category_relation scr
                ON scr.scr_id = catgy.category_id  
              INNER JOIN subjects subj
                ON subj.subject_id = '{$sId}'
            WHERE subj.subject_id = '{$sId}'
                AND subj.subject_id = scr.subject_id";

    $res = $this->db->query( $sql );

    if ($res) { 



        $results = $res->result_array();

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump( $results );
        echo "</pre>"
        exit;
```

**vardump**

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["category_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["category_title"]=>
    string(5) "terms"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["category_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["category_title"]=>
    string(6) "people"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["category_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["category_title"]=>
    string(8) "places
"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["category_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["category_title"]=>
    string(7) "works
"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["category_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["category_title"]=>
    string(8) "events
"
  }
}
```

Getting Database int type in string. What is the proper solution? Instead converting each array may be not good solution.

Comment: vote down for no reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database object should return correct value type in object. there is issue in PHP/MySQL older versions.

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/

Install php5-mysqlnd driver

```
apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
service apache2 restart
```

Reference:
[MySQL integer field is returned as string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323146/mysql-integer-field-is-returned-as-string-in-php)

[Check @advait answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25692758/612854)

Answer (score -1):

Try [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to convert `string` to `int`:

```
array_walk($results, function(&$a) {
    $a['category_id'] = (int)$a['category_id'];
});

var_dump($results);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/g95TiR)

When retrieving even integers from `DB` it is converted to string so you have to manually convert them back to `int`

Comment: I have list of function like these.. Do i use this solution each time?

Comment: @AlizainPrasla I can't guess your comment, though like you see you've to pass `array` into function and it will return `int` instead of `string`. Use function based on your needs

Comment: I think iteration is not right way. Its should return INT from database because Primary keys are in Int value.

Answer (score -1):

```
$new_int_array = array();
foreach($results as $value){
    $new_int_array [] = array_map('intval', $value);
}
print_r($new_int_array); //this is new array with int type values.
```

Comment: Unefficient to create new array when you can just change values of elements by reference !

Comment: try settype function for your array.

Comment: It's about to write script short and useful with best performance. Otherwise the same task can be solved with many ways

Comment: foreach($results as $value){
foreach($value as $value1){
        settype($value1, "integer");
}
    }

Comment: Can you please explain this code (in your answer)? You might get more upvotes that way!

Comment: foreach($results as $value){ foreach($value as $value1){ settype($value1, "integer"); } }
---------------------------------------------------------------------

with two loops we get internal values of arrays and than set there type to integer which is required.

Comment: are you want explanation of comment code or answer code.?

Comment: I think iteration is not right way. Its should return INT from database because Primary keys are in Int value.