# Integers being cast as strings on debian server

Tags: php, string, macos, integer, debian

We work on OSX locally when building our Ecommerce platform, but today two issues have come up with our installation on a Debian server with integers being interpreted as strings.

In our code we can obvious cast them to integers and it works fine, but this is quite a subtle thing to pick up and I was wondering if anyone had any experience in dealing with an issue like this? Is there a PHP configuration that I am not aware of?

Thanks

Comment: We need to see the code.

Comment: There's a lot of code, and it's happened in multiple places. Anyway, we worked out what it was, it was happening with data pulled from the database. Turns out it's because the server didn't have php5-mysqlnd installed. Anyway, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Resolved by installinh php5-mysqlnd on the server, answered on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323146/mysql-integer-field-is-returned-as-string-in-php