# JSON_ENCODE converts all array values to string in AJAX Request

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, ajax, json

I execute a simple AJAX Request, where i select some data from a mysql database. When i pass my Array back to Javascript, it always converts all Values in my Array into String, doesn't matter if its datatype was integer or boolean in my database.

## EDIT:

I just found out, that MySQLi always converts datatypes to string, so I guess thats the problem. json_encode works fine.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5323169/4720149

**SQL Statement**

```
   function getAll()
   {
        // Get all  buildings
        $db = new db();

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM building";
        $result = $db->runQuery($sql);

        $rows = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }     

        return $rows;
   }
```

**PHP Controller File**

```
function getBuildings(){

  $bu_db = new Building_Model();
  $buildings = $bu_db->getAll();

  echo json_encode($buildings);
}
```

**Javascript file**

```
var data = {
  action: "getBuildings"
};

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "controller/Building.php",
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log("Error in AJAX Request: " + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Instead of keeping the original datatypes from the database, it turns all values into Strings:

**Output**

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Obje...]
>0: Object
>1: Object
>2: Object
>3: Object
   ActiveCost: "20"
   BuildEfc: "0"
   BuildSfx: "0"
   BuildingEfc: "0"
   BuildingID: "1"
   Name: "Vogtei I"
   ResidentLvLNeeded: "0"
   ...
```

Does anybody know this problem?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

What PHP version do you use?

Try:

> echo json_encode($buildings, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK );

Comment: I use PHP Version 5.5.8. I could do that, but there are some values who are really strings and look like integer  and I don't want to convert them to integer. Isn't there a way to keep the original datatype? (String, Integer, also NULL)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has dynamic data types. So there is no specific data type for int string etc. same var object can hold all the data types. It will dynamically identify the type based on the operations you do on those variables.

Comment: I totally agree with that, but have a look at the php manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php in the example section, there are no quotes added to integer values.