# PHP : comparison operator === not working on hosting server

Tags: php

In the file `defines.php`, I have `define("YES",1);`.

I am including this file in the `login.php` page as

```
require_once('/defines.php');
```

where I have this check `if ($row['registered'] === YES)`. This is not evaluating to true. If I use double equals, it works. I did

```
echo $row['registered'];
echo YES;
```

and I am getting the output as

```
1
1
```

On my localhost machine, however, `===` is working fine. Why is this strange behaviour? Is there any dependency on production server?

PS : My hosing server is using PHP v5.4

**EDIT**

Var dump :
string(1) "1" int(1) 
But I have tinyint type in database, why I am getting string data type?

Comment: do a var_dump of both `$row['registered']` and `YES` to verify types

Comment: you may also try `(int)$row['registered'] === YES`. However you should always know what variable type you have and in case you don't doing a var_dump as DarkBee suggested is the best way to go

Comment: as others noted, since you're using strict comparison, `echo` is a useless toy.

Comment: "not working on hosting server" - and it doesn't work on local server either, does it?

Comment: Just cast it to int, `int($row['registered'])` Php converts it to string because... ..php

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323146/mysql-integer-field-is-returned-as-string-in-php

Comment: @Mihai Its not PHP that is casting this to string, it's the database driver

Answer (score 1):

Your database driver returns the value of `registered` as string

- you can either typecast your integer values and them compare them
  using  ===

  (int)$row['registered']
- or use the == operator instead

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/80649/2255129 for the differences of === and ==

Comment: * or use another database driver :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is

```
$var1 = '1';
$var2 = 1;

// this will be right
if ( $var1 == $var2 )
{ echo "'1' = 1"; }

// This will never be right
if ( $var1 === $var2 )
{ echo "'1' != 1"; }
```

in PHP you can not use === to match string and int or boolean.

eg.

> 1 == '1' = true
>
> 1 === '1' = false
>
> 1 === 1 = true
>
> true === 1 = false
>
> true == 1 = true

thats mean if you use === and not == its need to be same type like string === string or int === int

you need to use == if you want to match int and string, i do not recommend you combine string and int in a if statement.

convert you string to int, and make a match agin like this

```
$var1 = (int) $row['registered'];
$var2 = (int) YES;

if ( $var1 === $var2 )
{ echo 'your right'; }
else
{ echo 'you got a problem'; }
```