# handlebars.js #if statement within #each doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, codeigniter, handlebars.js

first of all, thanks for the help. I am sure I'm doing something stupid somewhere but i cannot figure it out and it's driving me crazy. I tried to dollow many articles and suggestion on SO that was working for the other users but not for me.

I am building an app in jQuery, using handlebars as for templating, and getting the data from a backend api built in codeigniter.

I am using an IF statement within an #each to display the check in a checkbox if it was already checked.
The issue is that the IF statement doesn't seem to work within #each, since it display all the checkboxes as checked if they clearly aren't.

the jquery function is the following:

```
var load_checklist = function() {
    var $checklistTable = $('#checklist-table');
    var $row = $('#checklist-row').html();
    $.get(BASE_URL + '/uapi/get_checklist', function(o) {
        var template = Handlebars.compile($row);
        $checklistTable.append(template(o));
    }, 'json');
};
```

this is the html piece:

```
<tbody id="checklist-table">
  <script id="checklist-row" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each checklist}}
    <tr data-id="{{title}}">
      <td>
        <label class="fancy-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" {{#if completed}}checked="checked"{{/if}}>
          <span></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">{{title}} completed {{completed}}</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">
        <button class="btn-view-fund btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn-view-fund btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </script>
</tbody>
```

and the output from the api is the following:

```
{
    "checklist": [{
            "checklist_id": "1",
            "user_id": "2",
            "title": "test1",
            "decription": "test",
            "action": "test",
            "action_target": "test",
            "completed": "0",
            "date_added": "2017-01-23 19:31:49",
            "date_modified": "2017-01-23 19:31:49"
        }, {
            "checklist_id": "6",
            "user_id": "2",
            "title": "test2\r\n",
            "decription": "test",
            "action": "test",
            "action_target": "test",
            "completed": "1",
            "date_added": "2017-01-23 19:31:49",
            "date_modified": "2017-01-23 19:32:17"
        }, {
            "checklist_id": "11",
            "user_id": "2",
            "title": "test1",
            "decription": "test",
            "action": "test",
            "action_target": "test",
            "completed": "0",
            "date_added": "2017-01-23 19:31:49",
            "date_modified": "2017-01-23 19:31:49"
        }]
}
```

I have alsot tried to do it through a helper adding but it doesn't work.

```
            Handlebars.registerHelper('ifIsOne', function(value, options) {
          if(value === 1) {
            return options.fn(this);
          }
          return options.inverse(this);
        });
```

this is the version I'm using

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

and jquery-2.1.1.min.js.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like your code is just testing the "completed" property to see if it's truthy - any non-empty string is truthy, however, so all your checkboxes will appear to have "completed" set to something true.

Comment: And your `ifIsOne` function tests to see if the value is the **number** `1`, when in your JSON the values are strings, so that won't work right either.

Comment: thank you so much. I just noticed that code-igniter is outputtng numbers as strings by default, so with the helper and using only == it works fine. I just need to undestand, how I can modify this setting in code-igniter. thanks again

Comment: the casting of everything as string that is happening in the API seems related to the DB driver, (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323146/mysql-integer-field-is-returned-as-string-in-php) and I haven't yet figured out how to change it.