# Every field in the array returned by PDOStatement::fetchAll() is of String type (PHP + MySQL). How can I reserve the original field type?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

Every field in the array returned by `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` is of `String` type (`PHP` + `MySQL`). I mean even those fields of `Integer` type also have quotes around the results.

How can I reserve the original field type? That means, if one field is of `Integer` type, then it won't has quotes in the array returned by `fetchAll()`.

Comment: I think that this is normal "behaviour". You have to exchange the data from mysql into your specific types. E.g. type casting or hydrating your objects.

Comment: this answer might help, fetchall always return result as string.check this answer for more details : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323146/mysql-integer-field-is-returned-as-string-in-php

Comment: The return-type is always a string from MySQL. PDO doesn't check what sort of column it is, just what value it has. Usually though, that's all you need - as `"3" == 3` (string of 3 vs integer of 3) is true. Can you show some examples why you need the original type?

Comment: @BenRoob Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: @AliBAGHO Thank you very much! Yes, that thread is very helpful for me!

Comment: @Qirel Thank you! Now I know. I have used to use `===` instead of `==` for long time, just feeling that it can provide more strict grammar check and more computing efficiency (even very slightly). My example can't prove the necessity of need for the original type. I just didn't know it before and felt curious.

Comment: Have you considered using the metadata from the database table and use that to identify the numeric columns and convert them as required? You could apply a function to each column of the result set after the fetch? It would slow it down slightly but would make it easy to use the result set?

Comment: Yes, actually I have done so, writing a casting function using `PDOStatement::getColumnMeta()` method in a `for` loop. Thank you very much!