# PHPMyAdmin - Column Defined As Int, Shows Up As String

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I've been debugging for days how to resolve a `!==` issue between two values. Turns out it failed because it shows up as a string instead of a int like defined in the database.

Here it shows as int:

[image]

But when using it, it's being defined as `string`:

```
var_dump($dbinfo['tmdb_revision']) . '<br>'; // the value from the database
var_dump($api[1]['tmdb']['revision']); // the dynamic value I compare the db value with
```

Results as:

```
string(1) "7"
int(7)
```

I can use

```
(int)$dbinfo['tmdb_revision']
```

But that seems weird because it's defined as int in the database and rather use that definition.

Is this a known issue and how can I resolve it?

---

$dbinfo is defined like so:

```
$titlecheck = $this->query("SELECT * FROM titles WHERE tmdb_name=:name AND tmdb_titleid=:skuid");
if($titlecheck->execute(array(":name" => $api[1]['tmdb']['name'], ":skuid" => $api[1]['tmdb']['titleid']))) {
    $dbinfo = $titlecheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // code starts here
```

Comment: Where do you define `$dbinfo` ? How do you do the query to the database?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I've updated the question with the asked information. I feel like there's nothing wrong with it since it outputs info from the database just fine, feel free to correct me on that

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your query and what you are seeing is normal and correct. See the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323146/mysql-integer-field-is-returned-as-string-in-php) which reads, in part, "When you select data from a MySQL database using PHP the datatype will always be converted to a string.".

Comment: @Dave That helped. Converted all strings to a int now and all works fine. Thanks!