# How to remove "" from data directly from a database in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to return information from a mysql database using php and need to get rid of the "" in the dynamic values.  I have tried using real_escape_string and trim but this has not worked.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $myArray= array(

   // array("running"=> 23),
   // array("walking"=> 54)

  
    array("running"=>$row['running']),
    array("walking"=>$row['walking'])

  );  
}

echo json_encode($myArray);
```

As the code currently stands it returns `[{"running":"23"},{"walking":"54"}]`

However, I need it to return `[{"running":23},{"walking":54}]` without the "" characters (It returns this using my commented out static code)

Comment: cast it as `(int) $row['whatever_number']`

Comment: Seems like you're storing these numbers as strings in the database. I think if you used an actual number column, `mysqli` would already return these values in the desired type. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL integer field is returned as string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323146/mysql-integer-field-is-returned-as-string-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK** parameter in the json_encode().

```
echo json_encode($myArray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK (integer)

Encodes numeric strings as numbers. Available as of PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: Thats a nifty option I always end up forgetting about, as its rare that I absolutely need to care about it.