# PHP JSON API - detect data types of return values

Tags: php, json, casting

im working on a `PHP JSON API` which returnes `json_encoded` multidimensional arrays.
Due to the fact, that `PHP` is a weak typed language - i have some problems with the returned data types on the client side as e.g. integers are returned as strings.

**Example of a response**

***Before json encode***

```
array() {
  ["users"]=>
  array() {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "983"
    ["email"]=>
    string(28) "xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx"
    ["username"]=>
    string(8) "xxx"
    ["verified"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["tutorial_completed"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["companies"]=>
  array() {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "170"
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) "xxx"
    ["trusted"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

***After json encode***

```
data: {
   users: {
     id: "983",
     email: "xxx@xxx.xxx",
     username: "xxx",
     verified: "2",
     tutorial_completed: "1",
   },
   companies: {
     id: "170",
     name: "xxx",    
     trusted: "1",
   }
}
```

I'm getting the data from a `MySQL table`.
The values are basically taken as they are.

**One solution, that works** is checking each key and then cast the numeric values by `intval()` or `floatval()` - but this would mean an enourmous effort for bigger arrays and the solution lacks in flexibility.

Is their a smooth way to automatically detects if the data type can be a numeric value as well and if so, cast it?

Comment: is there a way in the front-end side to send integers without quotes?

Comment: @Oyeme, sorry I don't get the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem: When you fetch from a MySQL database from PHP, the fields in the result are of string types or NULL no matter what the types of the fields are in the database. This is related to the MYSQL driver.

The solution:
You need to cast the numeric values yourself to the type you need in the array. Or, as you are converting to json, you can simply do it using:

```
$encoded = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

The numeric fields will be cast for you automatically.

Comment: You can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5323146/14066311 to learn more on how to deal with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `is_int()` function in your loop of fetching data from `mysql` and use `intval()` for which return true in making array, hope it helps

Comment: I have already tried that one, but `is_int()` is returning `false` because `PHP` considers it as `string`. If i check the value with `gettype()`, i get "string".