# Prevent MySQL PDO from returning numbers as strings

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PHP's PDO to query a MySQL database.  It returns numbers and integers as strings, and is messing with my JSON.

Is there a better way of fixing it other than type casting the values row by row?

```
array(2) { 
  ["name"]=> string(11) "Preliminary" 
  ["sell_price"]=> string(6) "864.00"
}
```

Comment: Guess I wasn't suppose to edit the main message!  Note that I am using PHP Version 5.3.14, and not using prepared statements.

Comment: do you simply pass result array to json_encode() ?

Comment: Keep in mind that PHP is dynamically-typed (or something like that), so it won't make much of a difference either way what type your variables are.

Comment: Yes, I pass the results to json_encode(), and then jqPlot takes the data and makes a plot.  The results are different if the numbers are quoted.

Comment: JSON only deals with strings.

Comment: @databyss: false - it supports numeric types: http://json.org/

Comment: @Marc B ahh yes, I stand corrected :) I was pretty sure it just encapsulated all data in ""

Comment: reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197005/how-to-get-numeric-types-from-mysql-using-pdo

Comment: All the answers here are ugly hacks. For the correct solution, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20123337/229792).

Comment: @jameshfisher Excellent! Gentlemen, please upvote this comment!

Comment: What @jameshfisher said...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using php 5.3.3 or higher you can use `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` as the second argument to `json_encode` to do this.

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Good answer.  Thanks.  Note this warning however which describes how a phone number like '+33123456789' will be converted to an integer.  http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#106641

Comment: All the answers here are ugly hacks. For the correct solution, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20123337/229792).

Comment: `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` is not suitable in some cases. Like one given [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#106641). But what is the reason mysql driver returns integer as string? Isn't there any better way!!

Answer (score 3):

Although @Explosion Pills works in this case for @user1032531's needs, it's not addressing the 1st source of the problem.

As you can see in the original question, on the PHP side the value from `sell_price` is already a `string`, although, as the user said, in the database it's stored as a "number" (we don't know if it's a `DECIMAL` or a `FLOAT`).

Well, when using PDO with MySQL a proper config may be required in order to get "numbers" as "numbers", as user @jameshfisher pointed out in his comment. You can follow [his link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197005/how-to-get-numeric-types-from-mysql-using-pdo) in order to get almost everything you need to get it working.

Appart from that, the accepted answer is working because without the use of the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` `json_encode` will send everything as text no matter the type of the variable, and when using it it will convert the value to a type based on guesses rather than the type of the original var.