# mysql query "SHOW COLUMNS FROM table like 'columnname'":questions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table like 'column name'"`. 
I have already tried some tests for some times, it seems be similar like "where `column name='column'`.

However, I just would like to confirm 
thank u very much in advance.

Also, I'd like to say, why cannot I use `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table = 'columnname'` ?

Comment: sounds right to me, but show your code to confirm!

Comment: Please provide more details on the specific issue you are having

Comment: the code is just also, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM table like 'colmunname'".

Comment: and i'd like to ask why cannot i use "SHOW COLUMNS FROM table = 'colmunname'.thank u very much

Comment: You don't have to keep repeating that comment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's more like

```
WHERE column_name LIKE 'column name'
```

Since it uses `LIKE`, you can put wildcard patterns in the parameter, e.g.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table LIKE '%id'
```

will find all columns that end in `id`.

If there are no wildcard characters, then `LIKE` is equivalent to `=`.

If you don't want to use `LIKE`, you can use `WHERE`:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table WHERE field = 'column name';
```

In the `SHOW COLUMNS` output, the `field` column contains the column names. The `WHERE` clause also permits testing other attributes, e.g.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table WHERE type LIKE 'varchar%'
```

will find all `VARCHAR` columns.

Comment: hi, thank u very much for ur kindness reply. but i'd like to know,if i dont want use "like",is it possible to use "="?

Comment: also, i'd like to say ,why cannot i use "SHOW COLUMNS FROM table = 'colmunname'":thank u very much

Comment: Because that's not the syntax. See the syntax that VMai copied from the documentation. If you want to use something other than `LIKE`, you have to use `WHERE` with an expression.

Comment: thank u. but i have tried "show columns from table set where filed= 'Id'" or ""show columns from table where filed= 'Id'"".i was told an error.could u pls help me if there is a correct way? thank u very much for ur kindness help again

Comment: Because you misspelled `field`.

Comment: i know .its show columns from table where field='Id'".thank u very much for ur kindness help.best regards

Comment: I know that, that's what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

SHOW ... LIKE behaves like the use of the LIKE operator in the `WHERE` clause of a common query:

> [SHOW COLUMNS Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-columns.html)
>
> SHOW [FULL] COLUMNS {FROM | IN} tbl_name [{FROM | IN} db_name]
>       [LIKE 'pattern' | WHERE expr]
>
> SHOW COLUMNS displays information about the columns in a given table. It also works for views. **The LIKE
>   clause, if present, indicates which column names to match.** The WHERE
>   clause can be given to select rows using more general conditions, as
>   discussed in Section 21.32, “Extensions to SHOW Statements”.

Emphasis by me.

Comment: hi, thank u very much for ur kindness reply. but i'd like to know,if i dont want use "like",is it possible to use "="?

Comment: also, i'd like to say ,why cannot i use "SHOW COLUMNS FROM table = 'colmunname'":thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

Where is used to get an exact match where as like is used to get a wider range of columns using wildcards.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table like 'my%";
```

The above will find all columns that begin with **my**.

Where as with a where clause you cannot use wildcards and will only get returned exact matches.
Obviously you could use where with `between`,`>` or `<` etc in other cases which would give you a wider range but still not allow you to use any wildcards.

Comment: hi, thank u very much for ur kindness reply. but i'd like to know,if i dont want use "like",is it possible to use "="?

Comment: also, i'd like to say ,why cannot i use "SHOW COLUMNS FROM table = 'colmunname'":thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

maybe this:
SHOW COLUMNS FROM accounts LIKE'id'