# Laravel returns array of ID's as string instead of integers (CentOS)

Tags: php, arrays, windows, laravel, centos

dear community

I'm actually building a project using Laravel (5.2) and AngularJS (Server on CentOS - Local/Testing on Windows 7), and i found something strange while requesting an array of Id's as seen on these screenshots:
[Response on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99hLW.png), [Response on Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIelM.png).

On windows i get an array of integers, and on centos i get an array of strings...

The question is, What could it be causing this, and how to get the same response on centos as on windows?

PS: this is the database

```
contacts
-----------------
id
name
lastname
phone
....

groups
-------------------
id
nombre

contact_groups
-------------------
contact_id
group_id
```

and this is the function i used on Model Groups.php

```
protected $appends = ['contactList'];

public function getContactListAttribute(){
    return $this->contacts()->lists('id');
}
```

Comment: It seems to be already solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174545/issues-with-laravel-on-different-os

Comment: Thanks!!, i didn't know the correct words to search this haha

Comment: If you can, set the question as answered ;)

Comment: Thanks Umbert P. this question has been already solved here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174545/issues-with-laravel-on-different-os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174545/issues-with-laravel-on-different-os)