# Numerics converted to a string with PHP and PDO to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Iam using PHP (5.6.8) to act as the middle tier between a MySQL database and returning the results in JSON format.

We are using the PHP extension (PDO) to do the database interaction, but have noticed that all numeric values get returned as a string. The database itself is running on a Linux installation, but during development, both the client and middle tier are running on Windows.

I set the connection parameter "ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES" to false but that made no difference. e.g. $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, false);

This is the PHP function that I am using to retrieve data and it is tied to the RESTful interface.

```
function getAllObjects() 
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_Objects ORDER BY 1";
    try {
       $db = getDB();
       $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
       $objects = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
       $db = null;
       echo json_encode($objects);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}
```

I also tried "mysqli" but I get the same results in that the numeric values are all converted to Strings. If I use the "cast_query_results($rs)" function on the net, I do get numeric converted correctly, but it seems to me that this is rather a fudge, rather than a solution.

Any ideas on how to get this to work natively please?

Comment: how are the "numeric" values entered in DB, as a string  or Int ?

Comment: How are the values represented in the database? Eventually provide table structure.

Comment: See for answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20123337/10126479

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can force `json_encode()` to convert string numbers to integers with:

```
json_encode($objects, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Only when PDO is built upon mysqlnd and emulation mode is off, then PDO will return int and float values with respective types.](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#returntypes)

So you have to make sure that mysqlnd is shown under PDO section in `phpinfo()` and `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` setting is set to `FALSE`.

Note that `decimal` values will be always returned as strings, as they always should be.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me using this code. I put it right after the connection is established with PDO: $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

Answer (score -2):

Excellent. I am still a bit of a newbie to PHP, so the json_encode option works best for me.

Comment: Please dont put thankyou's in answers, you will just get downvotes. Ooopps to late, Not mine by the way