# Why is_int on primary key value return string?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check if a member id  from a database , is an integer , but when i use `is_int` function on this data it return me false.. primary key should be an int no?

```
$query = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM `blog` WHERE `categorie` = 'Dossier' ORDER BY `date_ajout` DESC LIMIT  " . $offset . "," . $page_result . "   ");
$query->bindValue(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindValue(':page_result', $page_result, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
$id = is_int($value['id']);
    var_dump($id);
    echo $id;
}
```

Comment: You need to use `is_numeric` right? ***Note:**
To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string (such as form input, which is always a string), you must use `is_numeric()`.*

Comment: I tried with is numeric its working , but primary key type is integer so that's why i don't understand.

Comment: `var_dump($value['id']);` or `var_dump($id);`

Comment: How are you generating the `$value`? Mistake might be there.

Comment: Have you checked what `$value['id']` contains, as @Fred-ii- says, dump it and see.

Comment: I generate it with a foreach loop

Comment: @Trippy Please put the full code in your question. I am concerned about what and how you are assigning it.

Comment: try it without the loop and see what that says on a single pass (in a while loop) for that specific row. You may have other rows in that loop that are not ints.

Comment: @sebastianbrosch Ha ha.. Sorry buddy, I should have not said! :P I too removed my comment! :P

Comment: `primary key should be an int no?` - not necessarily; I've used things like ISO codes as primary keys, e.g. ISO 3166 alpha-2 codes for countries. There's no guarantee that your system isn't storing a number in a `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` field. Also depends on your database interface code - what exactly is generating `$data`?

Comment: @Trippy How do you get `$data`?

Comment: I just edited my post

Comment: @Trippy Looks perfect for me. What's your output of `var_dump`?

Comment: You're fetching everything from your query, that's why it's failing. If you `SELECT id` you'll see that your `is_int` will be TRUE.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Nopes. Looks alright to me. The `id` gets stored in `id` right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar OP's query includes strings and is using `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- So what? :)

Comment: Yes the id is stored in id, my var_dump output string(2)"12"

Comment: @Trippy Now get back to work. Show us the output of `var_dump()` man.

Comment: @PraveenKumar because of the foreach

Comment: what you want to do here is a `while` loop (not a foreach) and inside that, `if` and check on that specific row.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323146/mysql-integer-field-is-returned-as-string-in-php

Comment: I don't see anyone being nasty. Wow, some are just too sensitive.

Comment: Thanx @mitkosoft that's the perfect explanation i was looking for thx

Comment: @Trippy Who's nasty?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL integer field is returned as string in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323146/mysql-integer-field-is-returned-as-string-in-php)

Comment: big discussion for nothing :) in general regardless of the data type defined in your tables, PHP's MySQL driver always serves row values as strings.

Comment: @mitkosoft I use the procedural MySQLi and don't use prepared statements, but I get the right data type. Interesting.

Comment: Ok  that's what i wanted to know @mitkosoft

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079320/php-pdo-mysql-how-do-i-return-integer-and-numeric-columns-from-mysql-as-int for a very very detailed explanation.

Comment: @mitkosoft - what you wrote isn't true. If `mysqlnd` is installed, then you get appropriate string / int / float types in PHP. If not, then you get strings for everything. However, yes, a big discussion for not so much of a big deal :)

Answer (score 2):

In order for PHP to correctly represent data types from MySQL, you need to have MySQL Native Driver (mysqlnd) installed.

Link: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php

When you don't have native driver installed, PHP must guess what the type is. The safest type is `string`.

Function that can determine if a string-representation of something is actually a number is `is_numeric`.

Alternatively, as you did, you can coerce the type to integer using `intval($variable)` or `(int)$variable`.

Comment: Oh yeah, I do have `mysqlnd` installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :

```
if ((is_int($value['id']) != true)) {
  $id = intval($value['id']);
}
```

Now , it's ok