# PDO: 'Could not find driver'

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610489/php-ambiguous-floating-point-issue/36612691#36612691) and followed the instructions.

- I removed the default mysql driver `sudo apt-get remove --purge php5-mysql`
- I installed the Native Driver `sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd`
- I ran `sudo php5dismod mysql && php5enmod mysqlnd`
- I restarted php5-fpm and nginx

At this point I was presented with the following error:

> [2016-04-14 08:50:02] local.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /var/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:47

Why does PDO say *Could not find driver*?

Comment: *..Wow, thanks. I've learnt something new here and thanks for the link I wish I could've found that.* But, you ticked answer as correct there and even you replied.

Comment: Yes, this missing driver is a different issue to my question that was solved previously - i.e. the difference between homestead and a different set-up (which turned out to be the driver).  Configuration of that driver is then a separate issue - also this is more an Nginx config issue not an Apache issue

Answer (score 0):

The solution (for php-fpm/nginx) was to modify the **mysql.ini** configuration within the mods-available directory.

```
sudo vi /etc/php5/mods-available/mysql.ini
```

I replaced: `extensions=mysql.so` with `extension=mysqlnd.so`