# Laravel 5 - Collection is empty on remote server (integer/string error Apache)

Tags: php, apache, laravel

When I use where on collection in Laravel 5.2 on local server I have to use integer value to filter values, but when I deploy on remote server I have to use string value on where function. Like this:

```
$indicators = Indicator::get();
$main_indicators = $indicators->where('main',1)->all(); 
//$main_indicators works on local empty on remote  

$indicators = Indicator::get();
$main_indicators = $indicators->where('main','1')->all(); 
//$main_indicators works on remote empty on local
```

This happens only when filtering a collection, created by Eloquent query.
When I use where in eloquent query its working like this on every server:

```
Indicator::where('main',true)->get();
```

main is boolean (tinyInt(1) on MariaDB).

Migration:

```
$table->boolean('main')->default(false);
```

Local server: MacOSX, Xammp, PHP 7

Remote server: PHP 7, Apache

I want same code on every server, I want to change remote server, but I dont know what to set. Its really annoying develop two versions...

Database is the same on both servers.

Web server is Apache. Thanks

Comment: Database column type is the same on local and prod?

Comment: Yes DB is the same - same host, database, user, password

Comment: Column type is the same? i.e. INT?

Comment: Hmm, weird. What happens when you run it like this `->where('main', true)`?

Comment: Does the default on the server show `0` for `main` column?

Comment: ->where('main', true) is empty on local and remote. But this is only in collection, when I run eloquent query Indicator::where('main',true)->get(); It works everywhere

Comment: How do you mean? `get()` returns a collection...? What is `$indicators` - Indicator class you're injecting? i.e. Indicator $indicators, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115145/discussion-between-petkopalko-and-mike-barwick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was the MySQL driver: [PHP + PDO + MySQL: how do I return integer and numeric columns from MySQL as integers and numerics in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079320/php-pdo-mysql-how-do-i-return-integer-and-numeric-columns-from-mysql-as-int/20123337#20123337)

But It can be really easily resolved by setting cast to model like this:

```
//Indicator model
protected $casts = [
    'main' => 'boolean'
];
```

Comment: If you prefer. But I consider this almost a hack to messy code. You shouldn't need to declare or cast the `main` attribute like that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you're not using the `where` query properly. This needs to be specified ***prior*** to the `get` or all.

You're code should look like this (based on your current code):

```
$indicators = new Indicator; // Indicator::all() also works.
$main_indicators = $indicators->where('main',1)->get();
```

But that's ugly. Instead inject the `Indicator` class in your controller construct or the method itself. I'll use the controller injection method example below:

```
public function someFunction(Indicator $indictors) {
    $main_indicators = $indicators->where('main', true)->get();
}
```

Or just do:

```
$main_indicators = Indicator::where('main', true)->get();
```

Second example should be your go-to, IMHO ;)

Comment: But I need all indicators and then filter them in collection. But thanks for answer.

Comment: Yeah...? You still can...use first example I shared then. Don't run `get` until ***AFTER*** your filters.