# PHP sqlite is returning all strings no matter what data type is defined

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm running unit tests using the sqlite in memory database and I've run into an issue.

When I perform the tests using a mysql database, the following comparison works properly

```
if ($item->user_id === Auth::id())
```

It will evaluate to true if the numbers match and false if they don't. When I use the sqlite in memory database the conditional statement will **always** return `false` because the `user_id` attribute is returned as a `string` instead of the proper `int` data type.

I've read a few posts and comments saying this is a configurable thing for sqlite in PHP and others saying it cannot be changed. I want to use the in memory sqlite database for my tests but if I can't change this behavior I have to change my conditionals to use `==` instead of the more strict `===`. How can I change the behavior of the sqlite queries?

**UPDATE**

I've also tried adding this to the sqlite configuration

```
'sqlite' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
    'prefix' => '',
    'options'   => [
        PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false,
        PDO::FETCH_NUM => true,
    ],
],
```

This doesn't help either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The problem is actually with PDO](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3548), rather than SQLite or Laravel specifically, and in fact happens with all databases.  The fact that you are getting `int`s from MySQL suggests you are using [the `mysqlnd` driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079320/php-pdo-mysql-how-do-i-return-integer-and-numeric-columns-from-mysql-as-int/20123337#20123337), which solves this for MySQL.

The solution I went with was to [explicitly cast fields](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) in my model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'user_id' => 'integer'
];
```

Comment: while I agree this is a solution and might end up being what is needed, I would rather not have to add that to every model for every int column I have. Is there no way to configure PDO to not do this or perhaps a native sqlite driver as opposed to the PDO one? Isn't laravel configured to be using the PDO MySql driver by default?

Comment: @vane no, there is not

Comment: @vane This didn't feel ideal for me either, but I am not aware of another option.  And this way I am reasonably confident it will work no matter what DB or driver I use.

Comment: @Don'tPanic It works, I actually had come to this conclusion before you answered but didn't want to accept it as a solution since it kind of has a bad code smell to it. Unfortunately I fear you're correct in that this is the only real solution currently.