# A Laravel policy works differently on tests

Tags: php, laravel, testing

Laravel 7. I user http tests to check the availability status of my pages. But I noticed that in tests one of my policy works differently.

The controller method:

```
public function show(Competition $competition)
{
    $competition->load('registeredTeams.user', 'teams.user');

    return view('competitions.show', compact('competition'));
}
```

The policy method applied to it:

```
public function view(User $user, Competition $competition)
{
    return $user->id === $competition->user_id;
}
```

The test and its internal methods:

```
public function testCompetitionsPageTest()
{
    $user = $this->loginAsFakeUser();
    $user->commissioner = true;
    $user->save();
    $competition = $this->createFakeCompetition($user->id);
    $this->get('/competitions')->assertOk();
    $this->get('/competitions/create')->assertOk();
    $this->get('/competitions/' . $competition->id)->assertOk();
}

protected function loginAsFakeUser()
{
    $user = User::create(['username' => 'TestUserForTests']);
    $this->actingAs($user);
    return $user;
}

protected function createFakeCompetition(int $user_id)
{
    $competition = new Competition([
        'name' => 'TestCompetitionName',
        'type' => competitionTypes()[2],
        'tops_number' => 1,
        'self_confirm' => 1,
        'winner_points' => 3,
        'registration_end' => today()->toDateString(),
    ]);
    $competition->user_id = $user_id;
    $competition->save();
    return $competition;
}
```

When I load the tested pages in a browser, everything works just fine. However, when I test it, the next assertion doesn't work as it returns 403 code instead of 200:

```
$this->get('/competitions/' . $competition->id)->assertOk();
```

After some manipulations I figured out that it works correctly if I use non-strict comparison in my policy:

```
return $user->id === $competition->user_id;
```

Can you help me to figure out why my created user through `create()` and `actingAs($user)` id and user_id field of $competition have different types?

Edited (added requested information):
My competition migration:

```
    Schema::create('competitions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('info', 1000)->nullable();
        $table->string('logo')->nullable();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
        $table->string('type');
        $table->json('parameters')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger('self_confirm');
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger('tops_number');
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger('winner_points');
        $table->unsignedSmallInteger('round')->default(0);
        $table->date('registration_end');
        $table->unsignedSmallInteger('max_teams')->default(0);
        $table->date('finished')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Competition model (it contains a lot of methods to request and calculate additional data only, I included only properties):

```
protected $casts = [
    'parameters' => 'object',
];

protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'info',
    'registration_end',
    'self_confirm',
    'winner_points',
    'tops_number',
    'type',
];
```

### Update

I tested the values on different stages and it turned out that for some reason during the test an injected Model Competition has user_id property with the type of string for some reason.
In a browser it is an integer value as expected.

Comment: Please can you show the code for your `competitions` migration and also your `Competition` model.

Comment: I added this information to the question text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP sqlite is returning all strings no matter what data type is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805727/php-sqlite-is-returning-all-strings-no-matter-what-data-type-is-defined)

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier yes. It's exactly what caused the problem. I've already received the explanation from Taylor Otwell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was because of my test database type. It used sqlite, which has only string values in it after retrieving results.
I just removed two lines from my phpunit.xml in order to use my main connection for tests as well.

Removed lines:
    
`<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
<server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>`

Comment: I already had the same issue years ago; Here the reason https://stackoverflow.com/a/46806137/8068675 I'm not sure Laravel can do anything about it since it's not aware of the field type elsewhere than casts or migrations file.

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier, I found the problem. Check out this answer after my edition.

Answer (score 1):

Just making some assumptions on the code that you posted I think that, outside the test, `$competition->user_id` is a `string` value while inside the test it's an `int` value. You can easily verify this assumption.

This happens because `createFakeCompetition` forces the type `int` for `$user_id`, as you are running without strict mode, PHP converts the string passed to an inteteger, however this makes the comparison `$user->id === $competition->user_id` fail.

I hope to have been clear.

Comment: I checked your suggestion, and it turned out that it's vise versa. It's always an integer value outside the test. Even more, inside the test method it's still integer, but inside the policy method it magically becomes a string only within the test. Probably it's the dependency injection problem.

I suppose I found some sort of a bug.