# Radio Button is not 'checked' on localhost only (Laravel/Vagrant)

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

For some time I have a strange issue:
with standard syntax

```
{{Form :: radio ('somename', 'someval', true, ['adparam' => 'someparam'])}}
```

the parameter 'checked' does not render on the local host (mac, vagrant / box, laravel 5.4), but it works on a remote server ...

I have already broken the brain, in which direction to dig since I did not even notice the moment when it started work incorrectly (in fact, it worked some time ago)?

UPD:
A whole page is realy big, but the piece of code is

```
{{ Form::radio('certain', '1', true, ['data-case'=>$case->slug]) }} Возможный
{{ Form::radio('certain', '2', false, ['data-case'=>$case->slug]) }} Вероятный
{{ Form::radio('certain', '3', false, ['data-case'=>$case->slug]) }} Характерен для
{{ Form::radio('certain', '4', false, ['data-case'=>$case->slug]) }} Достоверный/Верифицированный
```

In fact, the issue shows up only when data in the controller matches with a view. If I have `$case->certain` and radio `certain` it does not work, but when I change radio name on some like `certain2` it works but has no sense, of course. As I mentioned the issue exists only on localhost and just disturb to develop.

UPD:
After fighting with debugging tools I have found that servers handle param in different ways.
For localhost works:

```
{!! Form::radio('sex', 0, true) !!}
{!! Form::radio('sex', 1) !!}
{!! Form::radio('sex', 2) !!}
```

For production works:

```
{!! Form::radio('sex', '0', true) !!}
{!! Form::radio('sex', '1') !!}
{!! Form::radio('sex', '2') !!}
```

The Question: where is hidden a setting for this (etc 1!='1')?

Comment: Any chance you can show us the HTML code that gets rendered on localhost? Ideally the entire <form> element if possible.

Comment: Edit your question with the code and propper code formatting please.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple radio buttons selected. Radio button groups allow a single selection. You need checkboxes in order to accomplish multiple selections.

Comment: I updated the example above. It does not work if I even use the current value like `$case->certain=='2'?true:false` in the third param... I mean it does not works in any combination (true/false), and this code Works on the remote server...

Comment: But as only as I change the name of radio button on any name different from data in the controller, it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes down to using different database PDO drivers.

Some return ints as strings, others return it as an int. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079320/php-pdo-mysql-how-do-i-return-integer-and-numeric-columns-from-mysql-as-int)

Temp solution is

```
    'mysql' => [
        'options'   => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true]
    ],
```

in config in `database.php`