# Laravel Model - should I cast foreign index integer keys?

Tags: laravel, model

When I make a new table in Laravel, I generally use the Laravel default id column definition: `$table->bigIncrements('id');` Say for example I have a `clients` table with that in my migration.

If I need a foreign relationship on another table, I 'll do it like this:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('client_id');                

$table->foreign('client_id')
      ->references('id')->on('clients')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

However, if I get model instances of both of those tables and render them with `->toJson();`, the `id` of the first table will be an integer in JSON, while the `client_id` of the second table will be a string in the json output.

Now I can make a `$casts=[]` array in the Model class for the second table to cast it to an integer, but I don't know if there's any reason I shouldn't do that. Or maybe I should ALWAYS do that. Is there any guidelines or suggestions about this sort of thing?

Comment: There is no need. It's just for mapping database types to PHP types (or objects), but unsignedBigInteger already maps to int.

Comment: I sometimes have a need in my javascript though, when one record has its ids as integers and the foreign relationship table has its foreign ids as strings.

Comment: Then your migration or your table definition is not what you think it is. The value is always returned as an integer in every case I've seen.

Comment: @miken32 I've definitely looked at everything and this is the second server this has happened on (I'm relatively new to PHP/Laravel, so that's as much data as I have). My migration definitely says `unsignedBigInteger`, and the column type, when I look in the SQL, is `bigint(20)`. I feel like it's 1 of 2 situations: (1) I should be expecting an integer in this case, and not worry about it, or (2) these servers I'm working on have a strange PHP setting that is converting number values to Strings when it comes from SQL (something which happens in normal PHP anyway iirc)

Comment: @miken32 something like this perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079320/php-pdo-mysql-how-do-i-return-integer-and-numeric-columns-from-mysql-as-int/20123337#20123337

Comment: From `artisan tinker` do `var_dump(User::first()->client_id);` substituting with whatever model you are using. If it says it's a string, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` in MySQL shows an integer type, then go file a bug report with Laravel.