# Pluck give string instead of integer

Tags: php, laravel, collections, pluck

I use laravel 9.25.1 and php 8.1.8.
I have script `$this->productId = $guest->products()->pluck('product_id')->toArray();`
This script give me **integer** in localhost but it gives me **string** in hosting.
I browsed everywhere to find the root cause and found in https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/pluck-id-integer-cast-to-string that it seems bug in laravel 5 but still happens in laravel 9?
Or is there anything I did wrong?

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz96H.png)
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHlUp.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return integer and numeric columns from MySQL as integers and numerics in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079320/how-do-i-return-integer-and-numeric-columns-from-mysql-as-integers-and-numerics)