# mySQL int returned as int instead of string in PHP mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, types

When I am pulling data from my table the type of the field is `int` and when I pull it with PHP it is staying as`int`. Yet on my server it is being pulled as a `string` (as I expect it to).

Both databases have the type of field as `int`. The code is the same on both of the machines, but the PHP version is slightly different. I can't see it being a result of a change in PHP, since this seems like a regression instead of an enhancement. I can't seem to find out why this is happening.

Local PHP version: 5.3.13

Remote PHP version: 5.3.3

Do you guys have any idea what is going on? This is quite odd.

Comment: which API are you using to "pull" the data with php? from which distribution repository are the php versions from?

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197005/how-to-get-numeric-types-from-mysql-using-pdo#answer-1197041 helps

Comment: @escitalopram Using the PDO driver