# Asking if a value is not the same as another and it always answers true in php if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I saw an answer that looks like it might address it but it's not looking promising looking around here because everything seems to indicate my code is fine. I'm trying to create a dynamic page where it loads certain information if certain conditions are met. Everything is showing up and working fine except my progress section. Can someone tell me why this isn't working?

```
<? php require_once("session.php"); ?> 
<? php require_once("connection.php");
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM progress WHERE email = '$email'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if ($row['admin'] == 0) {
    echo...
```

Then it echoes out my page with the dynamic content and if that value returns true at the bottom it redirects to the admin management page.

```
if ($row['progress'] !== 100) {
    $contract = $row['location'];
    $progress = $row['progress'];
    $mockup = $row['mockup'];
    echo "<a href=\"customer.php\">Contact</a><br />";
    echo "<a href=\"$contract\">View Contract</a><br />";
    echo "<a href=\"$mockup\">View Mock Up</a><br />";
    echo "<p>Progress: " . $progress . "%</p>";
}
```

This value always shows that the number in the database is not 100 even if the page echoes that it is 100% completed. This is a problem as the next stage on this is a payment stage but it won't load when every time it says it's true.

Comment: 100 !== '100'. Does `$row['progress']` contain an integer or a string?

Comment: It contains an integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing a type safe comparison, i.e. you're checking to make sure that `$row['progress']` and `100` and not just the same value, but the same type.

Values that come out of the database are always initially strings, whereas `100` is an integer.

Check to see if the database value is numeric with `is_numeric` and then use `intval` and then do the type safe comparison.

Comment: _"Values that come out of the database are always initially strings"_ => [not always true for `PDO`...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1197041/358679)

Comment: I know, just making a point about it's not a general statement that all data out of all databases in whichever manner would be strings, 'cause it could be misinterpreted (other people then the OP might find this answer in a search for answers, consider this a friendly footnote for them, I am not disagreeing with you). For `mysql_` AFAIK you are absolutely right.

Comment: Thanks that helps. I didn't think of how I was working with true and false through numbers and just didn't get why 100 was being different but it got it working.