# Database value with type int(11) is returned as string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a mysql database tablecolumn called customers_id with a datatype int(11).

With

```
    echo gettype($customers['customers_id']);
```

I get string as a result and

```
    echo is_int($customers['customers_id']) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

is returned with no.

Why is a integer value returned as a string?

UPDATE: I use `PDO` as access_layer.

Comment: What mysql access layer do you use? how do you obtain `$customers`?

Comment: Show your code, otherwise it's harder to know where the problem is.

Comment: @til_b I use PDO as access_layer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197005/how-to-get-numeric-types-from-mysql-using-pdo points to PDO having some kind of workaround to return native types instead of string, using mysqlnd driver. Its from 2009, though.

Comment: Because it works this way. Does it really matter?

Comment: ALL (non-null) MySQL values are returned as strings. For instance, if you had a BIGINT column with a high value, PHP wouldn't be able to handle it if it weren't a string.

Comment: Null also returned as strings btw

Comment: Mysqli with prepared statements returns right types thought, for ints and nulls

Answer (score -3, accepted):

One thing you can do is a

```
var_dump($customers); die();
```

which will give you all of the types that are returned from the database. In working with PDO in the past, I haven't had a problem with strings coming back where they should be INTs.

As a last resort, you could always cast it as an INT, where needed.

```
(!is_int($customers['customers_id'])) ? (int)$customers['customers_id'] : $customers['customers_id'] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

It comes back from PDO as a string. `is_int()` will not test true, however if you use `is_numeric()` it will test true if it is a string of numbers.

```
$myint = '1';
echo is_int($myint) ? 'yes' : 'no'; //returns 'no'
echo is_numeric($myint) ? 'yes' : 'no'; //return 'yes'
```