# Why is the whole JSON response data in string type?

Tags: json, apache, laravel-3

I am using Laravel3 `Response::eloquent`.

The result is in JSON format: `{"id":"1"}`. However I want the result like this: `{"id":1}` with `id` as a number, not string type.

I use apache and `Content-Type` is `application/json; charset=UTF-8`.

The problem only occurs on the production system. On my localhost the result is `{"id":1}`.

Is there any relevant setting for Apache or Laravel3 ?

Comment: If you are really experiencing different ways in your localhost and in production, I would recommend you do a `JSON.parse(responseText);`. That will ensure you will get the thing corrected all ways.

Comment: I'm useing angular in frontend, and I'm sure it not js issue

Comment: @sivatumma `JSON.parse();` is a JS function and not PHP.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to PHP and in turn eloquent using the wrong database driver. Starting from PHP 5.3 [`mysqlnd`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqlnd.php) is the default database driver with support for returning native data types.

Make sure that your using the `mysqlnd` driver for MySQL.

Also see [How to get numeric types from MySQL using PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197005/how-to-get-numeric-types-from-mysql-using-pdo#answer-1197041).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @user555. It is not a Laravel 3 or Laravel 4 issue, a mysqlnd issue, though.

Due to the wrong mysql client library your fetching table field types as strings then json_encode() is getting "string" as input and encoding to "string" as well.

I wrote an article about my experiencie on that here:

http://www.jmilan.net/posts/json-encode-data-type-errors-in-php
Hope it helps