# parse string element in JSON array to integer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

```
 $con = new DBConnector();
 $sth =  $con->Query("SELECT medicinename as label, factor as data FROM medicine_master_tbl limit 4");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
         $rows[] = $r;
      }
echo json_encode($rows);
```

there is no problem with my query,but the returned value is ..

```
[{"label":"rrp","data":"5"},{"label":"t","data":"34"},{"label":"tt","data":"4"},{"label":"nutrachin","data":"45"}]
```

i need the json array as like below..

```
[{"label":"rrp","data":5},{"label":"t","data":34},{"label":"tt","data":4},{"label":"nutrachin","data":45}]
```

which the data is considered as string in this array , i need to be parse it as integer .. thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the output of var_dump($r);

Comment: According to the php docs it should be output how you want it, what do you get if you var_dump/print_r $r inside the while?

Comment: So convert it to integer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy one.

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
     $r["data"] = intval($r["data"]);
     $rows[] = $r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your database connector would allow you to specify what type of data you are returning in the row, if `factor` is a numeric type. For instance, [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and mysqlnd can return native types (see [How to get numeric types from MySQL using PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197005/how-to-get-numeric-types-from-mysql-using-pdo)).

However, you can do the following:

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $r['data'] = intval($r['data']);
    $rows[] = $r;
}
```

This way, your JSON encoding will have an integer.