# Symfony3 Doctrine, disable PDO emulate_prepares?

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine, symfony

I'm quite new to Symfony and I'm learning about Doctrine.

If I try a

```
dump($this->getEntityManager()->getConnection());
```

I see that the PDO object has the EMULATE_PREPARES attribute set to 1. I wonder why, shouldn't emulated prepares be turned off? And if so, how to do that in doctrine configuration?

Comment: have you already see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089893/doctrine-doesnt-persist-entity-with-boolean-values-and-pdoattr-emulate-prepar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> shouldn't emulated prepares be turned off?

Nope, it shouldn't.

Although it could be recommended for the outdated PHP version for security reasons, but with any supported PHP version it's OK to have emulated prepares on.