# PHP is casting all array values to strings

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, casting, type-conversion

I have a problem with arrays.

On an old server all the data in arrays were with good types: a string was a string, a bool was a bool and an int was an int.

Now after a server change, all array values are "casting" to string. I cannot compare them with `===` against my integers because they are "string"

[This is how it looks](http://screencloud.net/v/uh1H) with `laravel` dd on the old server, versus [the new one](http://screencloud.net/v/Etrw).

Is there any php setting that causes this that should be fixed?

Comment: please post code NOT screen shots

Comment: It may be something related to how you're interacting with the database(PDO?), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197005/how-to-get-numeric-types-from-mysql-using-pdo

Comment: What's the difference between the old and the new server?

Comment: @NathanielFord why not? Now I "fix" it with changing === with ==. This is not question about using === but found the reason of my problem.

Comment: @Dagon I'm using Laravel, the same script, the same db stucture just moved to new server.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshots it looks like the following is happening.

- null value is changed to empty string
- integer values are now strings

**Database**

- Check the column types in the database are these still int and not varchar ?
- Since PHP 5.3.3 there is a json_encode param called JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK is this used ?

Maybe some framework is updated and using json_encode/json_decode with/without this param. This will result in integer values as strings.

```
echo json_encode(array('event_id' => '603'));
echo json_encode(array('event_id' => '603'), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

//and the output:

{"event_id":"603"}
{"event_id":603}
```

Comment: the colums are the same, I'm using laravel. And just move script to another server, db structure is 100% the same, the code is 100% the same, the diff is server.

Answer (score 0):

On laravel, you could just cast the string to become integer. For example:

```
return (int)$your_variable->your_column
```