# php pdo emulate_prepares false stringify_fetches false int still string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get numbers to output as such when fetching data from a MySQL database on a site hosted on ***Hostgator***.
PHP 7.0, MySQL - Server version: 5.5.48-37.8 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 37.8, Revision 727, Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73.

PDO parameters:

```
[
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false,
]
```

Yet even with these attributes, it still returns integers as strings.
How can I fix this?

Comment: How are your integers stored in the database?

Comment: show the actual query/fetching code...

Comment: The code involves abstractions, but the query is just `SELECT id, name FROM merchants ORDER BY name ASC`. In the end, `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` is called, which returns `['id' => '1', 'name' => 'foo']`. There are no modifications made on the data after fetching.

Comment: For the people who think this is duplicate (@JayBlanchard) - I have clearly tried the things I COULD do in the code to try and fix the issue. They are not helping. The mentioned duplicated topic does not offer any other fixes, aside from setting up mysqlnd, which I CANNOT do, as this is shared hosting.

Comment: If you unable to use the answer, it doesn't make your question non-duplicate.

Comment: By the way, any reason why strings do not suit you?

Comment: I am using PHP7 with strict data types.

Comment: Well, you need mysqlnd then.

Comment: @jurchiks really seems not a duplicate, anyways I shared my thoughts as an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45366230/1244597

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this SO question: [How to get numeric types from MySQL using PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197005/how-to-get-numeric-types-from-mysql-using-pdo) Also, make sure you have mysqlnd installed and activated. Look at `php --info` under `pdo_mysql`.

If it is, the output should look like this:

```
pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id:___ $
```

If that isn't installed, install it with this:

```
apt-get remove php5-mysql
apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
service apache2 restart
```

If that doesn't fix it, the issue is likely in the code you haven't shown us.

Hope this helps! 
Cheers!

Comment: >hosted on Hostgator...
The issue is not in the code. It works on my home machine, but not on the server, because the fetched ints are converted there.

Comment: @jurchiks http://support.hostgator.com/articles/php-modules

Comment: It looks like mysqlnd is installed on your home machine but not host gator then.

Comment: Is there no way to fix this without trying to get Hostgator to install mysqlnd?

Comment: And just to clarify, the query's result is returned by hostgator, php does the interpreting of that result.

Comment: On hostgator, do you have control over the php modules?

Comment: I would recommend contacting hostgator support and asking them.

Comment: There is a list of PHP PEAR modules only, not extensions. Doesn't look like this can be changed. Still waiting on the line to get to their support.

Comment: @jurchiks Well good luck! If it turns out you can't get the module, I can work with you to find another solution!

Comment: Well, pretty much the only simple solution is to use intval() where an int is required... A considerably more complex one would be to check actual table datatypes on every select and cast them to appropriate PHP datatypes, but screw that hassle. Not worth it for the project I'm working on.
Anyway, planning to move the project to a different server, so I'll just look for one that has mysqlnd available/default.