# Casting Issue in PHP PDO::FETCH_CLASS

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, casting, php-7

I'm tried to fetch the data from the State Table using `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`, but it returns the `int` field as `string`

**MySQL Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `INState` (
  `StateId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

**My PHP Code:**

```
class StateModel
{
    public $StateId;
    public $Name;
}

$stateArr = $db->query('SELECT StateId, Name FROM INState')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'StateModel');

var_dump($stateArr);
```

The Output of the above code is

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(StateModel)#4 (2) 
        { ["StateId"]=> string(1) "1" ["Name"]=> string(14) "Andhra Pradesh" } 
    [1]=> object(StateModel)#5 (2) 
        { ["StateId"]=> string(1) "2" ["Name"]=> string(10) "Tamil Nadu" }
)
```

In Table Schema the column `StateId` is marked as `bigint` but the code side it returns as `string`. How to get the property `StateId` as `int` instead of `string` using `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`? Kindly assist me.

Comment: [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1197424/6337519). Had the same issue as you, worked fine for me (php7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off-course @Mayank is right, but we can explicitly set the properties datatype in the constructor.

```
class StateModel
{
    public $StateId;
    public $Name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        settype($this->StateId, 'integer');
    }
}
```

Finally the output of your code is

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(StateModel)#1 (2) 
        { ["StateId"]=>  int(1) ["Name"]=> string(14) "Andhra Pradesh" } 
    [1]=> object(StateModel)#2 (2) 
        { ["StateId"]=>  int(2) ["Name"]=> string(10) "Tamil Nadu" }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select data from a `MySQL` database using `PHP` the datatype will always be converted to a `string`. You can check every `PDO Fetch method` return type is `mixed`. You can convert it back to an integer using the following code:

```
$id = (int) $row['column'];
```

Or by using the function `intval()`:

```
$id = intval($row['column']);
```

Comment: Is there is any optional setting to do this casting? otherwise the proposed solution needs to iterate the collection once again.

Comment: If you want to just display it, than there is no need to convert it. And if you want to do some calculation than you have to iterate it.

Comment: Some times I fetch some data and do some operation. Moreover I'm sending this to the angular UI app, there again an issue. So I asked by default if its return the int means no issue otherwise I will do it manually. Thanks for your kind information.

Comment: In angular app, we need to do sorting if the int is coming as string means sorting won't give the proper result.

Comment: In that case u have to iterate it. If I am not wrong, you have to iterate the result set as well to show each record, type cast at that time