# Store result of a query in an array using PHP and use the array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I am trying to store the result of an SQL query to in array using PHP

```
 <?php   
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$ser="********";
$db="********"; 
$user="********"; 
$pass="********";

$dbDB = new PDO("odbc:Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;Server=********;Database=********;Port=1456", $user, $pass);

$sth = $dbDB->prepare("SELECT top 10 [Country],[Customer Name],[Purchase Number],[Part Number],[Qty],[Local Revenue] FROM ********");
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
 ?>
```

Now I want to use the variable **$result** in JavaScript instead of defining it manually this way

```
    var result = [
            ["Austria", "Tech Data Service GmbH", "3508224010", "01HV707", 1, 1558.40],
            ["Austria", "Tech Data Service GmbH", "3508314557", "40M7578", 1, 102.40]
            ,...
            ];
```

My problem is, the variable **$result** is taking all the elements inside the array as a string.

I am using this variable to create a pivot table and it's causing me issue with the numbers, instead of making the SUM for example, it's concatenating them as one string.
Here is my script I added in the same file after the php part

```
<script>
var data1 = <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>;
console.log("data is:",data1);

var data2 = [
        ["Austria", "Tech Data Service GmbH", "3508224010", "01HV707", 1, 1558.40],
        ["Austria", "Tech Data Service GmbH", "3508314557", "40M7578", 1, 102.40]
        ];

console.log("data is:",data2);       
</script>
```

Here is the difference between was I expect and what I am getting
[image]

is there a way to store the result of the query in an array with keeping the type of element ? Or anything I should add to the script part so that it will work.

So instead of

**["Austria", "Tech Data Service GmbH", "3508224010", "01HV707", "1", "1558.400000"]**

I will have

**["Austria", "Tech Data Service GmbH", "3508224010", "01HV707", 1, 1558.40]**

Thank you.

Comment: are you sure that the values returned from your database are actually numeric (I mean in PHP, regardless of the column type in MySQL)? AFAIK json_encode does not have a problem. However, some database drivers though (libmysql I think does this) return everything from the DB as strings regardless of the column type. Are you using libmysql or mysqlnd as the underlying MySQL driver? (This is part of your PHP config, run phpinfo() and it should tell you). What version of PHP are you running? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197005/how-to-get-numeric-types-from-mysql-using-pdo

Comment: Use `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option in `json_encode()` to force numeric values where applicable. As for number of decimal points that could related to your float settings in db config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_encode()` can accept [additional parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php). The one that will help you out is `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`

> JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK
>
> Encodes numeric strings as numbers. Available since
>   PHP 5.3.3.

[Here's an example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aca1e223fa7c47f5977a765336d9756a84d14898) usage based on your code:

```
<?php
$array = ["Austria", "Tech Data Service GmbH", "3508224010", "01HV707", "1", "1558.400000"];

echo json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

// result:
// ["Austria","Tech Data Service GmbH",3508224010,"01HV707",1,1558.4]
```