# PHP PDO PostgreSQL always returns floats as strings

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to get native types out of a database query using PostgreSQL (v. 14) via PHP PDO.

Despite using `PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false`, the result comes out as a string, e.g. "1.2" rather than 1.2. Here's a reproduce case:

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO ("pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=database", 'username', 'password', array (
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false
));

$query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS floattest;";
$pdo->exec ($query);

$query = "CREATE TABLE floattest (id FLOAT);";
$pdo->exec ($query);

$query = "INSERT INTO floattest VALUES (1.2);";
$pdo->exec ($query);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM floattest;';
$statement = $pdo->prepare ($query);
$statement->execute ();
$data = $statement->fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump ($data[0]['id']);

// Expected value is 1.2 but what is returned is "1.2"

?>
```

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Until PHP 5.2 Postgre PDO returns strings even when the column is numeric, or datetime. You need to convert them implicitly:

```
$floatReturn = floatval($data[0]['id']);
```

From PHP 5.3 there are other solutions.
See [How to get numeric types from MySQL using PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197005/how-to-get-numeric-types-from-mysql-using-pdo)

Comment: Is this documented anywhere, that Postgres PDO doesn't return the correct types? There are references around the web suggesting it does.